# How to change Back to top label in Joomla 3 template Protostar

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0

Protostar is Joomla 3 default template. In the footer part, there is a link `Back to Top` which returns the user to the upper part of the html page.

The only document in which I have found this text so far is on location:

- *templates/protostar/language/en-GB*

But, the change of the text didn't actually change it on website. So, I suppose there is another location for this.

Where can I go and change it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the template is installed, that file would get moved to `language/en-GB/en-GB.tpl_protostar.ini`, so that would be the file that actually needs to get updated.

---

That being said, a better method is to use the language override feature on the admin side. You'll see in that file that the language key is `TPL_PROTOSTAR_BACKTOTOP` (what is to the left of the equal sign).

On the admin side, go to Extensions -> Language Manager. Then on the left side of the page, click "Overrides". Hit the new button and add `TPL_PROTOSTAR_BACKTOTOP` as the constant and whatever new text you would like there in the "Text" box.

By using the override feature you protect your site from updates if the template's language file is updated in a later version.

Comment: Wonderful. Thank you a lot, hope this'll someone else.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use your site with other languages than English, create the respective template language pack in folder templates/protostar/language/

As an example: If you use German on your site, create a folder named de-DE, copy the english files en-GB.tpl_protostar.ini and en-GB.tpl_protostar.sys.ini  into it and change their names to de-DE.tpl_protostar.ini and de-DE.tpl_protostar.sys.ini. Now you can change the respective line in de-DE.tpl_protostar.ini to TPL_PROTOSTAR_BACKTOTOP="nach oben"